# set Layout below CustomViewPager container

Tags: android, xml-layout

I want linear layout exactly below to CustomViewPager container. I have tried following code but doesn't work.  Main parent Layout to this both is CoordinatorLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout             
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.project.implementations.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </com.project.implementations.CustomViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container1"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/btnsave"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/btncancel"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can add an another linear layout using vertical orientation and put your both viewpager and linerlayout inside it

Comment: tried that. but buttons disappear from screen. :)

Comment: then you have to use a scroll view as well , especially if your app supporting horizontal orientation for small / medium screen sizes

Comment: @Pavneet Singh Thank you. After adding parent linear layout i set android:weightSum and android:layout_weight for child layout, and its worked.

Comment: i am glad that i could help :) happy coding